# MySQL not launching on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I can't get MySQL to launch via XAMPP, it was fine the last time I opened it a few months back;

Updated errors after I have followed the my.cnf recovery:

```
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-10-06 19:29:23 15fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 198755718 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-10-06 19:29:23 7920 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace bitnami_wordpress/wp_usermeta uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\bitnami_wordpress\wp_usermeta.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: There're already suggestions on how to fix it in your error report. Did you try any of them?

Comment: @DoanCuong I'm not going to lie, I'm just a designer so most of this technical stuff is chinese to me, I don't know where to begin even with the suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on the suggestions of the error log, I think you should try this. I planned to write this in a comment, but that will hard for you to read, so I'll make it as an answer instead

You can't launch MySQL because XAMPP can't open file `.\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd` as shown in

```
Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
```

And here is suggestions how to fix it:

```
1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
open the file, you should modify the permissions.
```

(1) is about permission. Go to `.\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd` and check if you have permission to read `innodb_index_stats.ibd`

```
2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
crash recovery and ignore that table.
```

(2) you can try to delete `.\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd`. My suggestion is copy `innodb_index_stats.ibd` to another location just in case anything else happen

```
3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

(3) If you can't delete `nnodb_index_stats.ibd`, you can try modify `my.cnf` file and set `innodb_force_recovery > 0` (you can use notepad or notepad++ to edit the file. It locate in `xampp\mysql\`

Try these first to see if it helps you

**UPDATE**
Please try to locate file `ibdata1` locate at `xampp\mysql\data` and delete it or rename it, then restart XAMPP, hope this gonna work for you

Comment: The problem I'm having is I can't find innodb_index_stats.ibd on my system at all, I've tried searching for the file but it just doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: Strange, it should locate in `xampp\mysql\data`, did you check that location?

Comment: Ahh yes it is there, I tried renaming the file and copying over the backup and nothing worked... I can't find my.cnf in xampp/mysql either?

Comment: So I done the recorvery but it's still failing to start: I've added the new errors to the main post

Comment: @DaveBurns answer edited, take a look and see if it help you :)

Answer (score 6):

I resolved same issue by deleting all of the **ib_logfiles** found in *~/x-ampp/mysql/data*