# mySQL not running in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, localhost

When I try running MySQL in XAMPP it gives me an error but everything else works fine. I already tried changing the ports on my.ini and I also tried Disabling two services but they were already disabled and enabled but MySQL still refuses to start.

Error:

```
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-10-22 17:24:42 8d8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1600614 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-10-22 17:24:42 5276 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace lg/users uses space ID: 5 at filepath: .\lg\users.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/slave_worker_info which uses space ID: 5 at filepath: .\mysql\slave_worker_info.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\slave_worker_info.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

I already looked for answers here (Everything that I mentioned I have tried was from here).

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL not launching on XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211817/mysql-not-launching-on-xampp)

Comment: Thanks, I checked that one out and did the last step and it worked.