# XAMPP MySQL service does not start

Tags: php, mysql

My XAMPP cant start MySQL it was working okay last day.
I have tried changing the ports in the ini file but no difference 
here is the error

```
151025 15:32:54 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-10-25 15:32:55 230c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1709328 in the ib_logfiles!
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
151025 15:32:55 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 1709328
151025 15:32:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
151025 15:32:55 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211817/mysql-not-launching-on-xampp

Comment: thanks, it did not really help me out . what I did was to reinstall xampp. turns out to be faster.