# mysql keeps crashing using xampp

Tags: mysql, database

Any help would be appreciated - please see below log

2016-08-02 12:12:15 8d4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 19045911905 in the ib_logfiles!

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages

160802 12:12:15 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...

160802 12:12:16 [ERROR] InnoDB: We scanned the log up to 19045911552. A checkpoint was at 19045911905 and the maximum LSN on a database page was 0. It is possible that the database is now corrupt!

160802 12:12:17 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.

160802 12:12:17 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

160802 12:12:17 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 19045911905

160802 12:12:17 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

160802 12:12:17 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

Comment: well but what do you need? Mysql is not starting or MySQL not launching on XAMPP?             check those: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly     or       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211817/mysql-not-launching-on-xampp

Comment: It's not launching on XAMPP..

Comment: I've also tried deleting the ibdata1 file and restarting XAMPP but it still doesn't work. Everything worked great until a restart of the computer!